# knn predictions with Clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, knn

I have a 60.000 obs/40 Variable dataset on which I used Clara, mainly due to memory constrains.

```
library(cluster)    
library(dplyr)    

mutate(kddnew, Att=ifelse(Class=="normal","normal", "attack"))
ds <- dat[,c(-20,-21,-40)

clus <- clara(ds, 3, samples=500, sampsize=100, pamLike=TRUE)
```

This returned a table with medoids.

Now I'm trying to use `knn` to do a prediction like this:

```
medoidz <- clus$medoids
r <- knn(medoidz, ds, cl=ds$targetvariable)
```

And it returns

> 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Can someone please shed some light on how to use it?

Comment: Please use reproducible data. `data(iris)` would work. Also remember to load the `class` package and show your partitioning to make this reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
require(cluster)
require(class)

data(iris)
ds   <- iris
ds$y <- as.numeric(ds$Species)
ds$Species <- NULL

idx      <- rbinom(nrow(ds), 2, .6)
training <- ds[idx,]
testing  <- ds[-idx,]
x        <- training
y        <- training$y
x1       <- testing
y1       <- testing$y

clus <- clara(x, 3, samples = 1, sampsize = nrow(x), pamLike=TRUE)

knn(train = x, test = x1, cl = clus$clustering, k = 10, l = 0, prob = T, use.all = T)
```

Though 3 is clearly a poor choice for the number of clusters in this dataset, so the prediction isn't good. Hopefully you'll choose the right number of clusters for your data and you can test your prediction strength with `prediction.strength` from the package `fpc` or in other ways.

Comment: Thank you! :) Can't vote up but you really helped. :) This is going into a for loop to find the best cluster size, 3 was just a simplification. However, I thought I had to use all the data.